# Using child combinator to make a child element visible on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a navigation menu. I have this HTML Code:

```
<div class="primaryNavigationContainer"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-5"><a href="http://merrycode.com/cheekoo/wp/">Home</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="http://www.xyz.com">MerryCode</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6"><a href="http://merrycode.com/cheekoo/wp/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.menu a
{
    font: normal 14px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    float:left;
    color:black;

}
.menu-item a{

text-decoration:none;

}

.menu li a:hover > ul {

    display:block !important;
}

.sub-menu
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
top:120px;
width: 170px;
height:auto;
background: #edebeb;
z-index: 100000;
z-index: 99999;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
list-style-type: none;

}
.sub-menu a
{
float: none;
}
```

I am trying to make the submenu visible when someone hovers over a menu-item. And the following CSS doesn't seem to work:

```
 .menu li a:hover > ul {

        display:block !important;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you fiddle it for us to edit.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/NjpNN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) instead:

```
.menu li a:hover + ul {
    display: block !important; /* The UL is a sibling of a, not child */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me one more thing? How can I make the menu stay on screen until user un-hovers the sub-menu or menu-item. Currently, it disappears when we un-hover the menu-item (sorry to bother).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `:hover` on the `<li>` instead the `<a>` tag, Try this:

```
.menu li:hover > ul {
  display:block !important;
}
```

With this is persistent when you hover the submenu too.